# Popup orientation changes twice

Tags: appcelerator

Popup orientation changes twice once orientation of device is changed. 
Please advise how to fix this issue in android Tab E device.

I have set popup - orientationModes:[Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT],

Thanks

Comment: You're setting that 'orientationModes' property to an Window, right?

Comment: yes to window only

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. Removed orientation landscape from tiapp.xml

Comment: Note that limiting the orientation is a bad practice: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Orientation-section-29004932_Orientation-Limitingorientationmodessupportedbyawindow